# Как в запросе выбрать данные только из партиции с указанием ее имени?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Мне известно название партиции, которое находится в таблице `all_tab_partition`.
Название партиции: `DF_387`.

Как мне выбрать данные именно из этой партиции?

Запрос вида:

```
select * from tm420.tbl_1 partition(DF_387)
```

выдает ошибку:

> ORA-14109: имена объектов с указанием секций могут использоваться только для таблиц и редактируемых представлений

В документации не могу найти примеры обращения к секциям таблицы.

Comment: Покажите скрипт создания таблицы

Comment: Нет возможности сейчас проверить. Попробуйте обернуть имя партиции в двойные или одинарные кавычки. Но по хорошему просто условие писать так, чтобы оракл понял, что надо в конкретную партицию попасть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синтаксис `partition(DF_387)` вполне правильнный ([partition_extension_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51143)).

Но так обращаться к партиции можно, как и сказано в сообщении об ошибке, только если основной объект таблица или редактируемое представление. Указанный в вопросе объект `tm420.tbl_1` не является таблицей.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create table tab (id number, name varchar2(10))
partition by range (id) (
    partition p1 values less than (1000)
);

create or replace view tab_1 as select * from tab;
```

Так будет работать:

```
select * from tab partition (p1);
```

> no rows selected

, а так нет:

```
select * from tab_1 partition (p1);
```

> ORA-14109: partition-extended object names may only be used with tables and editioning views

В этом случае, надо заменить на редактируемое представление, которое будет работать:

```
drop view tab_1;
create or replace editioning view tab_1 as select * from tab;
```